# Notify client when server has the result

Tags: c#, asp.net, push-notification

I want to make some data to be available over Internet. I have asp.net hosting, but size of my DB exceed allowed in my hosting plan. So I decided to do the following: I have the site where you can enter what data to search. Then this search string is stored in DB with unique Reference key. My PC where full database is located every two seconds looks if there are new requests and writes the result of this request. Next if client ask again with unique reference key specified, he get an answer. I was wondering is there any way to achieve the following: user enters search string, press search and when result is appeared in DB, it is pushed to user? By result appeared in DB I mean that value of some field was changed from null to some string in XML format. Thank you for answers.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the framework version you are using you can do something along these lines 
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4